# Spring Data REST Duplicates in search result when used with SORT

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have the below structure for 3 tables.

```
TableA {

String aId;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
List<TableB> tableB;

}

TableB {
String aId;
String bId;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
TableC tableC;

}

TableC {
String cId;
String name;
}
```

When I'm requesting a paged result, and wanted the result to be sorted by TableC's name, I use the query parameter

```
sort=tableB.tableC.name&tableB.tableC.name.dir=ASC
```

Now, this is giving me duplicate results on TableA because the query executed is containing a JOIN.

Any suggestions on how to fix it? I'm currently considering the use of a LinkedHashSet through a REST controller to fetch the result. But, then the problem is that totalELements on the Paged result will not be the same as the actual result.

Thanks,
Rakesh!